# How to update data to existing node in firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add students to a class that can be chosen a class from a recycleview.I am trying to update data to an existing child node in firebase.I used Intent and putextra() methods to get the child path .but when I am uploading,it creates a new child node with the same name.How can I solve this.Here are the codes I used.How can I get the path of an existing child and upload data to that child.

```
//get class path from a fragment
 String classid=getIntent().getStringExtra("keyclsid");


dataholder obj =new dataholder(name,regNo,regDate,guardName,contactNo,address,schoolName);



 FirebaseDatabase db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

//set path
DatabaseReference students= db.getReference("classes/"+classid+" /students");

//update to firebase
students.child(regNo).setValue(obj);
```

[image: here is my database,it was created a duplicate child]

Comment: So you basically say that you have two nodes with the sane name under the same node?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir when I am inserting new values to my existing node,it create a new node with the same name,but after that it is not happening,I mean continuesly new data inserts to second node,actually I want to know whether the code is correct or not,because I am beginner to all these.If you can help me it would be greatfull to my future works

Answer (score 0):

The Realtime Database is a Key-Value based Database.
Every Key has to be unique within one Node.
This is not an intended behaviour.

I would recommend you submit a [ticket for a bug report here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)